# oracle apex interactive report based on temporary table

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report, which retrieves all records from a temporary table. The insertion to the temporary table is done through a button **search** (which is on the same page) and with a pl/SQL dynamic action. The insertion takes place successfully. After this, I refresh the interactive report region using javascript code pasted below.  But the interactive report does not retrieve any row from the temporary table after the region is refreshed.

Has anybody solved it?

```
$('#temp_rpt').trigger('apexrefresh');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the Temporary table query. I altered the table query " ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS " into " ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ", and it works correctly now.